# on blur event for a drop down box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to execute a Php code when I click outside of a drop down box, I'm using this code :

```
$(function(){
  $('#right').on('click', '.categ', function(){
    var $p = $(this);

    /*if(/<input type="text"/.test(old))
      return;*/

    $p.load( "drop_down1.php")
       .find('select')
       .focus()
       .on('blur', function(){
         var value = this.value;
         var tex = this.text;
         $.post('listener_updates.php', {categ: value})
          .done(function(){
            $p.html(tex);
          })
          .fail(function(){
            alert('Could not update title');
          });
       });
  });
});
```

This code replaces a div by a drop down box when clicking on the div, no matter with this first part it works fine, but once the drop down box appears once I click on it, it shows the list but once I stop clicking, the list is closed without giving me the time to select the object I want, and when I click outside the box nothing hapens the list stays there when it should disapear and put the content I selected in its place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `blur` event for that.

```
 $('#right').on('blur', '.categ', function(){
        ..................
  });
```

Comment: Yes but I'm using it like I already used it for some text inputs having the same behavior

Comment: anyway it's not working that way I guess the problem is at .find() or .focus()